# Macron accent (a bar over the letter) in LaTeX not working

Tags: latex, diacritics, pdflatex, pdftex

I have the following .tex:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Required for accented characters

\`{o}  \'{o}  \^{o}  \"{o}  \H{o}  \~{o}  \c{c}  \k{a}  \l{}  \={o}  \b{o}   \.{o}   \d{u}  \r{a}  \u{o}  \v{s} \t{oo}  \o
```

which after using pdflatex produces the following::

[image]

i.e. \={o} and  \b{o} aren't producing the bars above and below the o and \v{s} is doing nothing.

What's going on here?!

Comment: Getting rid of \usepackage{times} and using \usepackage{times} instead works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross-posted on [tex.se] ([Macron accent not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/460203/5764)) where it was solved in comments.

Comment: @npross What do you mean?